# How to debug Windows dll from Delphi

Tags: windows, debugging, pascal, delphi-2007, user32

CodeGear™ Delphi® 2007 for Win32® R2 Version 11.0.2902.10471

Working on an application written in Delphi Pascal that calls a DLL (also Delphi) that changes a panel in the GUI. Occasionally during the change from view 1 to view 2, or visa versa, an access violation gets thrown from User32.dll.

However, it rarely, if ever, breaks in the debugger on the AV. Furthermore, I would like to be able to get a stack trace of why User32.dll is throwing. To do so I would need to load Windows symbols and somehow get Delphi to catch the AV so I can trace what and why.

How can I force Delphi to catch the error and then get a stack trace with windows symbols????

How do I get the windows symbols???

Comment: Access Violation at address 7734214F in module user32.dll Read of address 00000001

Comment: An Access Violation near memory address 0 usually means a `nil` pointer is being accessed.  More importantly, it is not safe to access VCL components across a DLL boundary, unless both EXE and DLL are compiled with the `rtl` and `vcl` Runtime Packages enabled (which then need to be deployed alongside the app). Otherwise, you should be using a BPL instead of a DLL. A BPL is a special kind of DLL that has built-in support for the RTL and VCL runtimes.

Comment: To enhance Remy's answer, use a tool such as madExcept. It will catch nil pointer use. It will provide a stack trace without the application being debugged.

Comment: Yeah, very likely that the mistake in your program is to have cross module VCL access without using runtime packages

Comment: I will try some of these. Just of note the GUI still updates and functions correctly. It is very rare that the AV is thrown. The application and dll does not directly call on any windows libraries. All communication to Windows is done through the Delphi libraries via their RTL.